# PSObject conversion Deserialized.System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, .net, generics, powershell-remoting

In c# am trying to call a power shell command-let and converting into C# objects and processing the data ....

Calling

> Get-SCVirtualNetworkAdapter -All

One of the Response Object :

```
IPv4Addresses                              : {12.12.12.12}
```

And MemberType is

> Deserialized.System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] Property

How to cast particular PSObject into string , List < String > ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this

new ArrayList(((ArrayList)(((PSObject)(vNetworkAdapter.Members["IPv4Addresses"].Value)).BaseObject)))